# Scrapy: Is Callback not calling parse_item?

Tags: python, scrapy

I think  Scrapy parse_item callback is not being called.

I am parsing a site which you can think of is like yellowpages but I cannot mention here. here is my code. removed some info i didnt consider necessary:

```
# convert unicode from html to string
fn = lambda t: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', t).encode('ascii', 'ignore')


class NowfloatsSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 
    allowed_domains = 
    start_url = 
    start_urls = 

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'[0-9a-zA-Z]+\/[-0-9a-zA-Z]+\-Stores\-in\-[a-z]+.*?\/', \
        r'[0-9a-zA-Z]+\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\-Stores\-in\-[a-z]+.*?\/', \
        r'[0-9a-zA-Z]+\/Stores\-in\-[a-z]+.*?\/', \
        r'[0-9a-zA-Z]+\/Stores\-in\-[a-z]+.*?\/\?page=\d+', \
        r'[0-9a-zA-Z]+\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\-Stores\-in\-[a-z]+.*?\/\?page=\d+'], \
        allow_domains=allowed_domains), callback='parse_item', \
        follow=True, process_links='clean_uri'),

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\/'],\
         allow_domains=allowed_domains), follow=True, process_links='clean_uri')
    ]

    def clean_uri(self, links):
        """
        cleans invalid url links generated with LinkExtractor
        """
        for link in links:
            search = invalid_regex.match(link.url)
            if search:
                subroute1, subroute2 = search.groups()
                link.url = urlparse.urljoin(self.start_url, '/'.join([subroute1, subroute2]))
        return links

    def parse_item(self, response):
        """
        parses the contents
        """
        self.logger.info('===================== INSIDE PARSING FUNCTION ===================== %s', response.url)
        item = TheItem() #defines the fields i want
        for banner in response.css('.store-box'):
            print "======= banners ==========="
            # print banner
            company_website_name = banner.css('.store-banner h3::text').extract_first().strip()
            company_website_url = fn(banner.css('.store-banner > a ').xpath('./@href').extract_first())
            category = fn(banner.css('.store-banner a').xpath('./span/@title')[0].extract())
            city = fn(banner.css('.store-banner a').xpath('./span/@title')[1].extract())
            company_num = fn(banner.css('.store-banner .telephone::text').extract_first().strip()).replace(' ', '')
            tags = map(lambda x: fn(x).strip(), banner.css('.posted-item ul li a::text').extract())
            print {
                'company_website_name': company_website_name,
                'company_website_url': company_website_url,
                'category': category,
                'city': city,
                'company_num': company_num,
                'tags': tags
            }
            item['company_website_name'] = company_website_name
            item['company_website_url'] = company_website_url
            item['category'] = category
            item['city'] = city
            item['company_num'] = company_num
            item['tags'] = tags
        return item
```

First of all, is this the way to call back callback? If so, why is it not being used. nothing prints while running scrappy.

Maybe someone could point out what am i doing wrong here?

There are similar questions here, but I am not sure what seems to the problem in the first place?

[Here is the log](https://www.pastiebin.com/58b0a31b6f92b)

Comment: Post your scrapy logs here

Comment: @Umair updated post. see log above.

Comment: maybe its because you have specified wrong selector `.store-box` ... do you see some items in inspect-element view by entering `.store-box` selector in Chrome?

Comment: if i run it in scrapy shell specifying the spider it runs. If i run it w/ scrapy.Spider Class, it runs. I am encountering this problem with CrawlSpider and rules. Not sure if it goes inside

Comment: @Umair i can verify that when using `def parse: return parse_item(response)` then it does work. but then need to manually define conditional rules inside parse which fails the point of using CrawlSpider in the 1st place

Comment: Could you please share the URL with me. that will be easier. I have been doing data scraping for 4 years and I never hesitated sharing website's url on SO ... :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136606/discussion-between-user2290820-and-umair).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

1. the `allow` in `LinkExtractor(allow=[])` did not have absolute url regex. It should have while i gave partial.

so something like:
`LinkExtractor(allow=['full_site_address_to_scrape/<regex>'])`

2. while `follow_link=True`, i was getting redirected so make sure `handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302]` is defined in the Class.